# RedirectMatch for multiple urls with queries

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect, query-string

I have a bunch of urls like:

```
url.com/internet-class-detail?schedid=521
url.com/internet-class-detail?schedid=523
url.com/internet-class-detail?schedid=525
url.com/internet-class-detail?schedid=545
```

Which I'm trying to redirect to:

```
url.com/internet-training
```

I've tried this rule in htaccess, but the query strings keep getting printed at end of redirect:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/internet-class-detail.*$ http://url.com/internet-training/
```

For example, going to:
    http://www.url.com/internet-class-details/?schedid=521

redirect you to:
    http://url.com/internet-training/?schedid=521

but I just want it to redirect to:
    http://url.com/internet-training/

Answer (score 0):

You can not match against query strings in a RedirectMatch directive, to match against query strings you need to use Mod_rewrite.

Try the following in htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /internet-class-detail\?schedid=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.com/internet-training/? [L,R]
```

Empty question at the end of the target url is important as it discards the orignal query strings.

Comment: Hey, thanks for trying to resolve. But this didn't work. No redirect occuring.